# Orientation of App Preview videos in Apple App store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm submitting a new app for publishing on Apple's App Store for iOS. One of the assets for the store is an App Preview or video of the app. I'm currently using only portrait oriented screenshots, as that seems like the current defacto standard for maximizing the number of screenshots that a customer can see. I have noticed that other apps have the video previews orientated in portrait as well, but when I upload my video to iTunesconnect it is showing up landscape. Is there a way to turn the video? How do I have the video appear in portrait? Typically I see other developers videos appear in portrait on the app store listing but play in landscape. Does a video uploaded in portrait automatically play in landscape? I would love to test this, but Apple's review policy makes that very difficult.

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this? I have the issue with my [Barcode Scanner App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/orca-scan-bulk-barcode-scanner/id1161117971)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the orientation of App Previews always shows in portrait even if the preview is in landscape.